# How can I get an address of a non-extern function (normal function) from another program using C?

Tags: android, c, bootloader

Recently I've been trying to get the address of a function in aboot (android bootloader) . It is called mmc_read. It is not an extern function but it's a function from a header.How can I get the adress of mmc_read from aboot (without modifying aboot) from aboot memory (stack)?

Comment: From stack pointer

Comment: Most probably not at all, or at least not in a useful way - Once an application is run, boot loaders are normally long gone to the bit bucket.

Comment: @tofro Not even from stack pointer?

Comment: No. A boot loader is the first thing your Android device will load from ROM, from disk, wherever. This will only be needed in the first few moments to load the OS and because of that the memory (as well as its stack and other data) occupied by it is typically invalidated completely by the OS starting up.

Comment: @tofro I wanted to make a fake boot image that makes a ramdisk load on the address of mmc_read. Boot images have privileges to access the aboot physical memory

Comment: If you want to know where in an image a special function has ended up after linking (I think that could be the question) You would need the map file the linker has produced on build.

Comment: @tofro http://blog.azimuthsecurity.com/2013/05/exploiting-samsung-galaxy-s4-secure-boot.html?m=1